# Why does emacs in an xterm on a Mac interpret c-h as backward-delete-char?

Tags: macos, emacs, x11, xterm

C-h is correctly interpreted has 'help' in Carbon Emacs.app and using /usr/bin/emacs in Terminal.app. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.  Emacs describe-bindings shows c-h is rightly mapped to help.  So it seems like xterm or X11 sees a c-h keypress and then sends a backspace to emacs.  Can this behavior be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here:
http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html#Xterm

Apply palm, with force, to forehead.

Many thanks to those that responded.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did exactly to solve your problem? Your link did not help solve the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check the `Advanced` tab of the Settings in use in the `Preferences` for `Terminal.app`.

```
Terminal -> Preferences-> Settings -> [settings name] -> Advanced
```

and ensure that `Delete sends Ctrl-H` setting is unchecked.

EDIT:  Sorry, I misread your question.  This answer might be helpful for someone who is having trouble using `/usr/bin/emacs` under `Terminal.app`, a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, or befuddle, depending on your point of view. Scroll down to about 5.4 and start there...

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html

...and welcome to the life long hobby of fiddling with your .emacs :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter what goes into .emacs.  Both the delete key and c-h chord produce the same key value ^?.  This is the test: In emacs try this c-q c-h and c-q DEL.  Emacs in an xterm on a mac produces ^? both times.  Emacs in Terminal.app produces ^H and ^? respectively. What I can't figure out is why emacs in an xterm treats c-h as ^? by default.